# Combinatorics (one to one?)

Tags: combinatorics

Is the following defined as one-to-one?

f: Z → Z, f(n) = ((n+1)/2) + 2

I think it is one-to-one, since for every value of f(n) there is only one value of n. However, when n is 2, f(n) is 3.5, which is not in the realm of Z. Does that mean that the function is not one-to-one?

Since f: Z → Z, are we supposed to only look at the cases where n and f(n) are both in the realm of Z?

Comment: To begin with, $f$ is not well-defined because of what you pointed out. If, instead, the domain was the set of odd integers, the function becomes well-defined and turns out to be one-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we are dealing with odd integers, (because this maps to $\mathbb{Q}$ if they are even). Suppose not, then there exists $n \neq k$ such that $\frac{n+1}{2}+2=\frac{k+1}{2}+2$. Solving algebraically this implies that $n=k$, a contradiction. Therefore this is one to one.

Comment: so you are only supposed to look at the cases when n and f(n) are both in the realm of Z?

Comment: If this is all you have been given in your problem then I would just dl it for the cases when $n$ is odd. And as Ahmed Hussein pointed out this is not defined for when $n$ is even since $\frac{2k+1}{2}\notin \mathbb{Z}$.